# Fixing the regular expression to accept new line

Tags: regex

Hi i am working on this regular expression.

https://www.debuggex.com/r/giVfbILJPyJCk3Ti

It works for second case

```
15. Sleep deprivation impairs our ability to
a) focus our attention
b) learn new information
c) transfer information to long-term memory
d) All of the above
Ans:  d
```

But for the first case there is \n in the question. how to i skip that \n in the question

```
 1. Which of the following 
 can be classified as learning?
 a) Development of neural connections in the brain
 b) Using crutches while your broken leg heals
 c) Writing with your left hand while the right hand is injured
 d) Acquisition of reading skills
 Ans:  d
```

Comment: What's your platform?

Comment: its java.([ \\t]*\\d+\\.[^\\.]+\\n(?:[ \\t]*[a-zA-Z]\\)[^\\n]+\\n)+[\\s]*)(Ans: [A-Z])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just include the newline character as an option (by changing `[^\n]` to just `.` with the `/s` modifier), and then make the question-gobbling quantifier `+` its non-greedy variant `+?`:

```
([ \t]*\d+\..+?\n(?:[ \t]*[a-zA-Z]\)[^\n]+\n)+[\s]*Ans:[^\n]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-0Vgm9OItugEZE4W)

Note that Debuggex seems to render `.` and `\.` identically in the graph, but they have very different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

You could save yourself a headache by using the inline form of the `s` (*DOTALL*) modifier here.

```
(?si)([ \\t]*\\d+\\..*?Ans:\\s*[a-z])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WGW18VYi7ECGr4Ni)